# Alexa Skill Works in Website, returns "Something went wrong" on device

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to developing Alexa skills but I have created a very simple skill that is written in C# and hosted in Azure.  At the moment it simply returns a JSON message.

```
public class AlexaController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("api/alexa/demo")]
    public dynamic Pluralsight(dynamic request)
    {
        string version;
        version = "5";
        return new
        {
            version = "1.0",
            sessionAttributes = new { },
            response = new
            {
                outputSpeech = new
                {
                    type = "PlainText",
                    text = $"Finance build is version, {version}"
                },
                card = new
                {
                    type = "Simple",
                    title = "TeamCity",
                    content = "Version identifier"
                },
                shouldEndSession = true
            }
        };

    }
```

My utterances are:

```
    HelloWorldIntent hello
    HelloWorldIntent hi
    AMAZON.HelpIntent assistance needed please
    AMAZON.HelpIntent i need assistance
```

Intent schema is:

```
    {
      "intents": [
        {
          "intent": "HelloWorldIntent"
        },
        {
          "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
        }
      ]
    }
```

When tested with the website it works fine:

```
    {
      "version": "1.0",
      "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
          "text": "Finance build is version, 5",
          "type": "PlainText"
        },
        "card": {
          "content": "Version identifier",
          "title": "TeamCity"
        },
        "speechletResponse": {
          "outputSpeech": {
            "text": "Finance build is version, 5"
          },
          "card": {
            "content": "Version identifier",
            "title": "TeamCity"
          },
          "shouldEndSession": true
        }
      },
      "sessionAttributes": {}
    }
```

However when I test it on my Echo Dot it says "Something went wrong".

I have checked and the skill is enabled and that it is using the correct account.
Is there anyway to get more detail to what is happening?

Comment: take a look at cloudwatch to capture exception

Comment: I don't have any experience with cloudwatch but I'll take a look.  It is almost like the skill isn't enabled (but it is) and that Alexa doesn't (or can't) invoke the Azure web api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the language I had specified for the skill. 
I am based in the UK and had sent the language to English (U.S.), this meant that the skill would be in the skill store for the United States (but not in the UK skill store).

Adding a new language (set to English U.K.) allowed the skill to be tested on my device in the UK.